# Count number of ids by Month SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this, I hope to count the number of ids by month. I used the following code but it does not work.

```
id                  date_time
1390880502018723840,2021-05-08
1390881127930372100,2021-05-08
1390881498270736386,2021-05-08
```

```
SELECT   twitter.tweets.id
WHERE    Month(twitter.tweets.date_time)=01 AND Year(twitter.tweets.date_time)=2021 ;
```

Comment: "By month", but your query only counts for the single month Jan 2021. Do you mean the count of *distinct* ids or just a plain count of rows? Please be precise. Also, what's the exact data type of `date_time`? Looks like `date`?

Comment: Why is the column called date_**time** when it apparently doesn't contain a "time"?

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use count() function and to_char to get year month part of date in one column:

```
SELECT count(witter.tweets.id)
WHERE to_char(twitter.tweets.date_time,'YYYY-MM')= '2021-01';
```

you can generalize it for all the month/year by using group by :

```
SELECT to_char(twitter.tweets.date_time,'YYYY-MM') , count(witter.tweets.id)
group by to_char(twitter.tweets.date_time,'YYYY-MM');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get counts for all months since Jan 2021:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('month', date_time), count(*)
FROM   twitter.tweets
WHERE  date_time >= '2021-01-01'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

If `id` can be `NULL` (which should be disallowed for an `id` column), use the slightly more expensive `count(id)` instead.

Count of *distinct* IDs:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('month', date_time), count(DISTINCT id)
FROM   twitter.tweets
WHERE  date_time >= '2021-01-01'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

For only Jan 2021:

```sql
SELECT count(DISTINCT id)
FROM   twitter.tweets
WHERE  date_time >= '2021-01-01'
WHERE  date_time <  '2021-02-01';
```